# Add Logo To Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application that is using a Navigation Controller. I didn't realize you couldn't add a UIImage to the header of the Navigation Controller on the storyboard. What is the best way to implement a logo through code if you want it centered on every screen? Is there a way to do this through storyboard or is code the only way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by Interface Builder, just dragging UIView into Navigation bar: [image: Custom view as brand]

You can achieve it also from code. Just set your custom view to titleView of navigation item.

```
// MARK: - Lifecicle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.titleView = BrandView()
}
```